# Writing unit test case for AllocWithZone method for singleton class

Tags: objective-c

I have unit test methods

```
-(void)setUp
{
    objectofClass=[ClassName shared];
}

-(void) testAllocWithZone
{
     STAssertNClassName *oneMoreObject=nil;oThrow(oneMoreObject=[ClassName allocWithZone:NSDefaultZone()],testing);
}
```

what should be the value of oneMoreObject?
Is it nil or sharedObject..???

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the code you provided. It depends on how you implemented the singleton. I usually don't bother making it impossible to create extra instances, just make it easy to create the single instance and use it properly.